# Can' select tools a number of drawings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select, tools, drawing

I am using ArcGIS 10.8 and I want to add some labels at the feature class of points. So, I draw some lines to indicate the label per point. I want to remove some of them, but the Select tools can't select those drawings and I can't figure out why does it happen. Some of the drawings can be selected but a number of them not. I activated and reactivated the toolbar "Draw" but nothing changes. I also opened this .mxd using first a blank map but nothing changed as well. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you draw the line on data view or layout view ? (element draw on data view are annotation while those in layout view are graphic, the graphic element wont be visible in data view and selecting annotation on layout view require to double click on the data frame before attempting to select...)

Comment: @J.R. thanks for your comment. I draw them at the layout view. The fact is that the drawings that can't be selected are also not visible in the data view, while the selectable drawings are visible in Data view.